# xpath or xslt (1.0) to find max number of rows in a grid with blocks of arbitrary length

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

**Context and ultimate objective**

Consider the below XML which should create the grid in the image. Each col element represents a cell (whether empty or containing a region) with a width and length. For a given block, the starting row (latitude) is known, the ending one not.
Note there is no `<row latitude="6"/>` because that row is already used up as part of the *Desert States* and *Deep South* blocks. Similarly, `<col timezone="PDT"/>` is missing for row 3 because that cell is already taken up by *North West*.

I need to know how many rows I need to make the final grid. In this example, I would need 10 rows.

**Question**

My current approach is to work out the timezone that has to highest sum of length.

```
sum(//col[@timezone='EDT']/@length)
```

The problem with the above xpath is that the timezone is hardcoded here (and in the real application is actually an axis with a very large set of possible values).
I've tried keys and muenchian grouping but to no avail.

What xpath 1.0 or xslt 1.0 can I use?

**XML**

```
<rows>
    <row latitude="1">
        <cols>
            <col timezone="PDT"  width="1" length="1">Canada</col>
            <col timezone="CDT"  width="1" length="1">Canada</col>
            <col timezone="EDT"  width="1" length="1">Canada</col>
        </cols>
    </row>
    <row latitude="2">
        <cols>
            <col timezone="PDT" width="1" length="2">North West</col>
            <col timezone="CDT" width="1" length="1"></col>
            <col timezone="EDT" width="1" length="1"></col>
        </cols>
    </row>
    <row latitude="3">
        <cols>
            <col timezone="CDT"  width="1" length="1"></col>
            <col timezone="EDT"  width="1" length="2">NY/NJ</col>
        </cols>
    </row>
    <row latitude="4">
        <cols>
            <col timezone="PDT" width="1" length="3">Desert States</col>
            <col timezone="CDT" width="1" length="1"></col>
        </cols>
    </row>
    <row latitude="5">
        <cols>
            <col timezone="CDT"  width="2" length="6">Deep South / Bahamas</col>
            <col timezone="EDT"  width="2" length="6">Deep South / Bahamas</col>
        </cols>
    </row>
    <row latitude="7">
        <cols>
            <col timezone="PDT" width="1" length="2">California</col>
        </cols>
    </row>
</rows>
```

[image: grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as I *think*) you want to know the largest sum of `length` of any timezone, you need to group the `col` elements by their timezone, sort the groups by their sum and get the sum value of the first (or the last, depending on the sort order) group.

Here's an example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="col-by-TZ" match="col" use="@timezone" />

<xsl:template match="/rows">
    <xsl:variable name="n">
        <xsl:for-each select="row/cols/col[count(. | key('col-by-TZ', @timezone)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="sum(key('col-by-TZ', @timezone)/@length)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('col-by-TZ', @timezone)/@length)"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <output>
        <test>
            <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
        </test>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Replace the `test` part with the actual logic you want to apply using the `$n` variable.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I wouldn't have thought of this solution.  Apropos, the use of count(. | x)=1, I'm assuming it performs grouping because if the current node exists in the key the count=1.  Is that an alternative to the usual Muenchian pattern with generate-id() or would that not be suitable here?

Comment: Both methods are provided in the original article: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html